# How to write fraction inside each span that represents index of the parent div / total number of divs?

Tags: jquery

Using jquery, how do I write a fraction inside the span that represents index of the parent div / total number of divs with class item?

```
<div class="item">
    <span>1/3</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <span>2/3</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <span>3/3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :)

```
var div_tot = $('div.item').length; //count total of divs

$('div.item').each(function(i) {
    var no = i+1;
    $(this).find('span').text(no+'/'+div_tot);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like that?

```
var items = $("div.item");
var count = items.length;
items.each(function(i){
    $(this).find("span")[0].firstChild.data = i.toString() + "/" + count.toString();
});
```